# Text to movie from commandline

Tags: bash, mplayer, video-editing, video-encoding

I need a script called `myslide` which does the following:

`myslide -f 15 -t 20 "Hello World"`

produces a movie file (to be played by mplayer), which just displays "Hello World" in the center of the screen in font size 15 for 20 seconds.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities presented here, using.

- (1) *[AviSynth](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1333264)*
- (2) *convert ([imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php))*

*EDIT:* Both scripts have now been condensed and modified to play only a **single** frame for the duration of however many seconds are specified. `mplayer` can handle very low FPS (eg. *0.008547009* and *0.003154574* FPS worked fine, ie. 117 and 317 seconds playing time).

*NOTE:* On the Ubuntu 10.04 machine. `mplayer` does not play the first frame, so I've needed to include 2 frames to achieve the specified time. So, be aware that another player may play both frames and thereby double the playing time.

*AviSynth* is a versatile/poweful frame-server. There is no GUI. It is a scripting language for non-linear audio-video editing/creating/filtering.
Being a frame server, it does not need to create a video on disk. It can serve the video/audio directly, frame-by-frame, to any AviSynth aware tool, be it a media player or encoder...

AviSynth is Free and Open Source Software written for Windows (have I lost you? :) ...  Attempts were made, but it was not successfully ported to *nix (I believe the developers tried but it got bogged down as its original design was heavily hooked into Windows *stuff*.  It does, however, *work well* under `wine`.  The *wine* version of `mplayer` and `Avidemux` can process **.avs** scripts (there are others; eg [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), and [AvsPmod](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=153248) which is a mini-"IDE" GUI for Avisynth).

Here is an AviSynth script to do what you want.

```
myslide  15 20 "Hello from AviSynth"
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
fontSize=$1; sec=$2; text="$3"
>>test.avs printf 'Blankclip( 2 ,width=640 ,height=480 ,fps=1/float(%s), color=$000000)\n' "$sec"
>>test.avs printf ' \ .Subtitle("%s", font="Arial", size=%s, text_color=$ff0000, align=5)\n' "$text" "$fontSize" 
wine avs2yuv.exe  test.avs -  2>/dev/null |
ffmpeg -b 100 -i - "test.mp4" 2>/dev/null

mplayer test.mp4
```

---

[avs2yuv](http://akuvian.org/src/avisynth/avs2yuv/) is a command-line program, intended for use under Wine, to interface between *Avisynth* and Linux-based video tools.
*avs2yuv* only reads a video stream, but *AviSynth* can frame-serve audio and video to `Avidemux` via `AvsProxy` (which ships with Avidemux)...

### ---

Here is another way, using `convert` from package `imagemagick`. This method creates a series of .jpg images.

```
myslide  15 20 "Hello from convert"
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
fontSize=$1; sec=$2; text="$3"
FPS=$(awk 'END{print 1/'$2'}' /dev/null)
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize $fontSize -gravity center -size 640x480 caption:"$text" "test$$0.jpg"
cp test$$0.jpg "test$$1.jpg" # Add 1 extra; mplayer doesn't play ist frame (on test system)
ffmpeg -y -r $FPS -b 100 -i test$$%d.jpg test.mp4
rm  test$$*.jpg # remove temp images

mplayer test.mp4
```

Comment: The resulting .mp4 from the above example is 8.4 KiB, regardless of the playing time... The make/encoding time is very fast for the `convert` method at *0m0.111s*. The `AviSynth` takes *0m1.237s*, which is probably because of the need to initialize `wine` and the extra step of needing `avs2yuv` to bridge the windows/*nix divide.

Comment: Re. AviSynth's `Subtitle` filter: I haven't used it for quite a while and forgot it only handles a single line. I've been mainly using another filter which reads the more elaborate *Advanced Sub-Station Alpha* subtitles **.ass** (and many more).. `.ass` may be *the*, most customizable subtitle format available.. The filter is called `TextSub` and is part of [VSFilter (TextSub & VobSub)](http://avisynth.org.ru/docs/english/externalfilters/vsfilter.htm). To make multi-line captions, I use a script, but [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) is a great **.ass** subtitle editor; *good documentation*..

Comment: @Alexar: Peter’s script looks fine to me.  If you are aware of a problem with it, please describe it in a comment and give Peter a chance to fix it.  I voted to reject your suggested edit because it looks like vandalism (to me).